# How does visual studio 2022 assemble C programs into assembly code

Tags: c

I selected Generate assembly file in Project properties, but no assembly file was generated after compilation.

Want to compile intermediate files, assembly files.

I use visual studio 2022 is the community edition, is it not functional impact.

Comment: I think you're getting confused between assembly language in the traditional sense, and building an assembly in a .NET language. An assembly in .NET is an executable file or DLL containing code in CIL, which is then compiled into native code at runtime.

Comment: There is an option called "Assembler Output" available for C and C++ projects, which would give you an additional file containing the assembly language output of the compiled code. However that is not really used often, since you'd usually just compile directly to an object file, library or executable instead

Comment: Also, assuming you selected "Assembler Output", if you also selected "Whole Program Optimization", the .asm files only appear after you build the whole program (and not after compiling a single file).

Comment: Thank you for your reply，The problem was solved，I also need to set up "Whole Program Optimization".Thank you .